# How to upload pom.xml and jar to a maven feed

Tags: maven, azure-devops

I have this application with this structure

```
├── README.md
├── abc
│   ├── app
|   |    |__pom.xml 
│   └── test
|        |__pom.xml
├── xyz
│   ├── adds
│   |   ├── pom.xml
│   |   ├── src
│   |   └── target
│   ├── encryp
│   |   ├── pom.xml
│   |   ├── src
│   |   └── target
│   ├── error
│   |   ├── pom.xml
│   |   ├── src
│   |   └── target
│   └── utils
│   |   ├── pom.xml
│   |   ├── src
│   |   └── target
├── wls
│   └── pom.xml
└── pom.xml
```

When I execute `mvn package` the directory adds, encryp, error and utils generate their JAR file in the target directory.
I need to upload the JAR and pom.xml from adds, encryp, error and utils directory. Also the pom.xml from wsl, abc(app) and abc(test) directory to azure artifact to later be able to download these as dependencies.